# Meta-cognition tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

Could we create a tag for the topic of `meta-cognition`, that is "thinking *about* thinking", or more completely (from Wikipedia):

> Metacognition is defined as "cognition about cognition", or "knowing about knowing". It comes from the root word "meta", meaning beyond.[1] It can take many forms; it includes knowledge about when and how to use particular strategies for learning or for problem solving.[1] There are generally two components of metacognition: knowledge about cognition, and regulation of cognition.[2]

To me it seems essential for a site focused on pedagogy.

Comment: Thank you for your proposal. This is mainly a procedural remark: tags are created by a question being tagged with it. (It is best there are at least two question, otherwise the tag will be auto-deleted.) Thus, to create the tag it would be necessary to have a specific question that needs the tag. If such a question, or questions, exist, please, mention it/them. Added: I had not realized you just asked such a question. Sorry.

Comment: I created the tag.

Comment: @quid Sorry for the late response, but yes -- if I would have gotten your message earlier, I would have linked to my own question! Thanks for making the tag!

Comment: No problem. Your are welcome. If you would write a brief tag-wiki excerpt that would be great. It could be more or less what you quote, but it is preferable not to use the same texts for license reasons.

Comment: Here's a draft: "Meta-cognition is the subject of the study of cognitive processes involved in activities such as teaching, learning, or problem solving, and the study of the subsequent regulation of those cognitive processes based on knowledge regarding them."

Comment: Thanks! You could add it at http://matheducators.stackexchange.com/edit-tag-wiki/276 as suggested edit. (Or I will copy it over in some time.) [I hope the link works; but I think it should as suggested edits are posisble.]